# Detect 3D direction of an impulse with accelerometer

Tags: math, accelerometer, physics, estimation

I know that what I'm going to ask could sounds crazy, but I'm trying to figure out how to resolve a problem in a smart way.

It's quite difficult to explain my problem, that's why I made an hand-made draft downloadable from here :) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5049281/static/Images_Impulse_Direction.zip.

- images in that zip (copied by Spektre)
  [image: setup]
  [image: impulse1]
  [image: mpulse2]

The setup can be approximated with a pipe endorsed on a rubber wall. The pipe is firmly connected (whit an unknown position and orientation) to a IMU equipped with an accelerometer and a gyroscope (sample frequency 110 hz).

I would like to discover the direction of the pipe axis (expressed in the IMU reference system) analyzing the data acquired during some taps at the end of the pipe in the same direction of the pipe axis. The taps are applied with the palm of the hand. In the figure the direction should be just on X axis.

I think that if the motion is just a translation (I could verify it checking if gyroscope data is close to zero), the acceleration (with the gravity removed) during the tap should have the same direction of the pipe axis.

Is there a smarter solution than just apply an high-pass filter to the signal an then save the direction of the sample with the higher magnitude?

Thanks for your help!